# What's the meaning of this sentence and what's the grammar structure of it?

Tags: meaning

This is part of the comment rules of one blog.

`Shameless self-promotion is well, shameless, and will get canned.`

(source: https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html )

I can't understand this sentence at all. Is this a typo or really a meaningful sentence? If so, please share the meaning of it and how to grammartically analyze it.

Comment: I think there's a missing comma : "Shameless self-promotion is`,` well, shameless, and will get canned." It's a statement of the obvious, and the general meaning is that self-promotion will be punished.

Comment: I think you're right! What should I do now? Wait for someone to answer?

Comment: I guess it should be: **Shameless self-promotion is, well, shameless and will get canned.** - Describing the syntax: - Shameless self-promotion (Subject), Is (Verb), Well (Adverb), shameless (Complement), and will get canned (Compound sentence with the subject omitted).

Comment: @JennyaChang : I'll do an answer then

Comment: 'Well' here is a pragmatic marker (hesitation or mitigation) and as such is a parenthetical, and as usual needs setting off from the matrix sentence.  But here, I'd include the adjective within the dashes: "Shameless self-promotion is – well, shameless – and will get canned." The second 'shameless' has more bite than the first ('Shameless self-promotion' is hardly jarring), and is used to underline the seriousness of the offence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a missing comma in the sentence :

> Shameless self-promotion is **,** well, shameless, and will get canned.

Between `is` and `well`. This indicates that what follows is a statement of the obvious : something shameless is indeed shameless.

As for the general meaning, it is that self-promotion in this forum will be punished.

Answer (score 0):

> Shameless self-promotion is well, shameless, and will get canned.

If you use this site to outright (**shameless**) promote yourself (**self-promotion**), honestly (**well**), that is without shame (**shameless**). Thus, that promotion (**and**) will be discarded in the trash (**get canned**).

Structurally, the sentence parallels: Red apples are—really—red, and will get peeled.

Simpler: We do not allow self-promotion.